# Jersey 2.26: register @Inject in ResourceConfig bindFactory cannot convert Factory to Supplier

Tags: java, json, forms, rest, jersey-2.0

I'm now using Jersey and I want to Inject a `GeneralForm` map into the Resource class context, which accepts all `application/json`, `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format submits.

I follow the instructions specified under the Jersey documentation:

https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e17033

#### GeneralForm.java

```
package cn.easecloud.jrf.provider;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GeneralForm extends HashMap<String, Object> {
}
```

#### GeneralFormFactory.java

```
package cn.easecloud.jrf.provider;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class GeneralFormFactory implements Factory<GeneralForm> {

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Inject
    public GeneralFormFactory(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralForm provide() {
        GeneralForm result = new GeneralForm();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GeneralForm t) {
    }

}
```

And then I register that Factory into my ResouceConfig:

```
package cn.cwhale.bowei;

import cn.easecloud.jrf.provider.AuthenticationFilter;
import cn.easecloud.jrf.provider.GeneralForm;
import cn.easecloud.jrf.provider.GeneralFormFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringLifecycleListener;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

@ApplicationPath("/api/*")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppConfig() {

        packages("cn.cwhale.bowei");

        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(SpringLifecycleListener.class);
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(ContainerRequestFilter.class);
        register(CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.class);
        register(AuthenticationFilter.class);

        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(GeneralFormFactory.class).to(GeneralForm.class)
                .proxy(true).proxyForSameScope(false).in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });

        property("encoding", "utf-8");

    }

}
```

But then I failed because the `bindFactory` method accepts a `Supplier<T>` argument which the `Factory` class did not implemented.

[image]

And when compile:

```
方法 org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.function.Supplier<T>>,java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>)不适用
  (无法推断类型变量 T
    (实际参数列表和形式参数列表长度不同))
方法 org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.function.Supplier<T>>)不适用
  (无法推断类型变量 T
    (参数不匹配; java.lang.Class<cn.easecloud.jrf.provider.GeneralFormFactory>无法转换为java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.function.Supplier<T>>))
方法 org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(java.util.function.Supplier<T>)不适用
  (无法推断类型变量 T
    (参数不匹配; java.lang.Class<cn.easecloud.jrf.provider.GeneralFormFactory>无法转换为java.util.function.Supplier<T>))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jersey 2.26 made some changes to its DI support. First it removed HK2 as a hard dependency and added an abstraction layer. The new framework uses some of the names from HK2 but the packaging is different. For instance the `AbstractBinder`. You can see in your code, that there is no `hk2` in the package name. This is the new abstraction layer Jersey uses.

The new layer makes a lot of use of Java 8. For instance with the `bindFactory`, it no longer uses the HK2 `Factory`, but instead uses the Java 8 [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html). For for `bindFactory` you would now make your factory implement `Supplier`

```
public class GeneralFormFactory implements Supplier<GeneralForm> {

    private final HttpServletRequest request;

    @Inject
    public GeneralFormFactory(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralForm get() {
        GeneralForm result = new GeneralForm();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and where can I find the correct documentation?

Comment: That's the right (most current) documentation, they just haven't gotten around to updating it.