# Jersey 2 - Request scoped binding vs Singleton binding

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm learning `Jersey` and trying to build a rest api. But I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between various bindings - `bind()` , `AbstractBinder()`, `bindFactory()` and also the scopes - `RequestScoped` , `Singleton` and `PerLookup`. What are the differences between them and when to use which one?

e.g. Say I have some request specific data passed into the request header. I want to use this data multiple times (say in resource classes, DAOs etc) during the request processing. What I figured is that I'll use a `request filter` and extract the data using the `ContainerRequestContext` and store it to some class. But i'm not able to figure out how to bind this class so that I can access it later. Which binding to use in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind()` and `bindFactory()` are methods in the `AbstractBinder` class that you use to bind your services in the registry. The `AbstractBinder` is what you register with Jersey so that it knows to configure all your bindings. You use `bind()` to bind the service itself. You use `bindFactory()` to bind the service using a `Factory` (or `Supplier` in 2.26+) to create the service.

`RequestScoped` means that the service is scoped to the request, meaning that it will be the same instance for the lifetime of the *request*. You would use this scope when the service is dependent on information tied to a request, like request headers.

`Singleton` scope means that there will only be one instance of the service for the lifetime of the *application*. You would use this scope when the service can safely be used at anytime without being tied to any request.

`PerLookup` means that a new instance of the service will be created every time it is *looked up*, either directly through the `ServiceLocator` (or `InjectionManager` in 2.26+) or via an `@Inject` (or other injection) annotation. Even though this is the default scope, the `RequestScope` and `Singleton` scope would be more appropriate for most of the use cases in the context of a Jersey application.

For your use case where you want to get information from the request context and use it in the service, you would use a `RequestScoped` service and use a `bindFactory()` with a `Factory` (or `Supplier` in 2.26+) and inject the request context into the `Factory` and use the context to create your service. You can see more explanation in [How to inject an object into jersey request context?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666797/2587435). If you are using Jersey 2.26+, you'll also want to read [Jersey 2.26: register @Inject in ResourceConfig bindFactory cannot convert Factory to Supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48656116/2587435)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation