# How to create a "Custom Injection Provider" (factory) without jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, cdi, supplier

Is there a way to achieve the same result described [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/ioc.html#d0e17033) not depending on jersey but pure jax-rs? I'd like to create a Custom Injection Provider like Jersey so I can inject MyClass extracting custom data from HttpServletRequest

```java
@Inject
protected MyClass myClass;
```

I also found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655865/jersey-2-26-register-inject-in-resourceconfig-bindfactory-cannot-convert-facto) useful, it works the same with `java.util.function.Supplier` but Jersey is still needed in this code:

```java
bindFactory(MyFactoryOrSupplier.class)
.to(MyClass.class)
.in(RequestScoped.class);
```

**EDIT:**

CDI is also a good alternative, but pure jax-rs is preferable

Comment: `@Context` and `@Provider` as defined in jax-rs specs

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: There's [a hack using `@Path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996225/2587435). Other than that, there is no pure JAX-RS way. JAX-RS doesn't specify any injection features, because it is part of Java EE, and Java EE already has CDI. Any solution (without CDI) will be implementation dependent.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the situation. So, how could be a possible solution with CDI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out this solution using CDI:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyFactoryOrSupplier {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public IMyClass getMyClass(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (IMyClass) request.getAttribute("MyInjectedClass");
    }
}
```

and then in my servlets:

```
@Inject
protected IMyClass myClass;
```

beans.xml

```
bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
```

Actually `MyClass implements IMyClass` because I don't what `MyClass` to have a public constructor with no-args and this did the trick.