# Replace AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory in Jersey 2.26

Tags: java, java-8, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Hi all I´m struggling migrating from Jersey 2.25 to 2.26 since, it has a break change in a internal class of the library `AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory`

They claim in the issue sections that since the package is internal it should not be used. But they dont offer a solution or workaround.

Any idea how can I replace the use of that class for something else to continue using the provide implementation as I´ve been doing so far?

```
class MyOwnFactory extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory[Future[Object]] {
  override def provide: Future[Object] = getContainerRequest.getProperty(Constants.individual).asInstanceOf[Future[Object]]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be to use a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and inject the `ContainerRequest`, as the `Supplier` replaces the HK2 `Factory` and all `AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory` is is an HK2 `Factory` that injects the `Provider<ContainerRequest>`. Just look at [the source](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.25.x/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory.java)

**See also:**

- [Jersey 2.26: register @Inject in ResourceConfig bindFactory cannot convert Factory to Supplier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48655865/2587435)
- [Registering a custom ValueParamProvider in Jersey 2.27](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50975973/2587435)

Comment: Thanks on Monday I’ll take a look